# How to change an anchor appearance and keep it until an other anchor is clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, anchor

What I want to do is to change an anchor name "page 1" to "[page 1] while changing the color of the link. I somehow managed to change the color, but it doesn't change back if I click on an other anchor.

```js
    var current = 1;
    var totalPages = document.getElementById("pageContainer").childElementCount;


    function showPages(id = 1) {
      if (id < 1 || id > totalPages) 
        return;
      curr_page = document.getElementById("page" + current);
      curr_page.classList.add("pageHidden");
      curr_page.classList.remove("pageDisplayed");

      target_page = document.getElementById("page" + id);
      target_page.classList.add("pageDisplayed");
      target_page.classList.remove("pageHidden");
      current = id;
    }
```

```html
         
    
    <div id="pageContainer">
      <div class="pageDisplayed" id="page1">
        <p>blah blah</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pageHidden" id="page2">
        <p>blah blah on a second page</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pageHidden" id="page3">
        <p>blah blah on a third page</p>
      </div>
    </div>     
         
         
         <h2 id="main">pages : 
  <a href="#" onclick="this.style.color='red';" onclick="showPages('1')">1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="this.style.color='red';" onclick="showPages('2')">2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="this.style.color='red';" onclick="showPages('3')">3</a>
          </h2>
```

I added the script I'm using to switch pages in case some of the value can be used to change the style of the anchor clicked on. Thank you.

Comment: post your `HTML` too

Comment: I added the html. though it's very simple.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: you said that you click some anchor tags but I DON'T see any anchor tag ? In general, your issue isn't clear, would you mind explain more ?

Comment: ":active" is trigger while clicked. on release it is not colored anymore. Sorry, I've removed the anchors by mistake while editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the color in the onclick function you should run function which checks all of the links and sets the color (or classname) depending on the clicked element.

```js
function toggleColor(elem) {
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
  anchors.forEach(function(anchor) {
    if(anchor === elem) {
      anchor.style.color = 'red'
    } else {
      anchor.style.color = ''
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="nav-link" onclick="toggleColor(this)" onclick="showPages('1')">1</a>
<a href="#" class="nav-link" onclick="toggleColor(this)" onclick="showPages('2')">2</a>
<a href="#" class="nav-link" onclick="toggleColor(this)" onclick="showPages('3')">3</a>
```

Comment: The result is the same as my code. It doesn't reverse to the original color when you click on an other link.

Comment: @Braisque I edited the code example to snippet so you can see that it's working

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use multiple onclick function try this**

```js
    var current = 1;
    var totalPages = document.getElementById("pageContainer").childElementCount;


    function showPages(id = 1) {
      if (id < 1 || id > totalPages) 
        return;
      curr_page = document.getElementById("page" + current);
      curr_page.classList.add("pageHidden");
      curr_page.classList.remove("pageDisplayed");

      target_page = document.getElementById("page" + id);
      target_page.classList.add("pageDisplayed");
      target_page.classList.remove("pageHidden");
      current = id;
    }
```

```html
         
    
    <div id="pageContainer">
      <div class="pageDisplayed" id="page1">
        <p>blah blah</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pageHidden" id="page2">
        <p>blah blah on a second page</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pageHidden" id="page3">
        <p>blah blah on a third page</p>
      </div>
    </div>     
         
         
         <h2 id="main">pages : 
              <a href="#"  onclick="showPages('1');this.style.color='red';">1</a>
              <a href="#" onclick="showPages('2');this.style.color='red';">2</a>
              <a href="#" onclick="showPages('3');this.style.color='red';">3</a>
          </h2>
```

Comment: It's also working. But the result remain the same. Once clicked, the link doesn't go back to its original color.